# Ropsten Ethereum not showing transaction information

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth

I am using `geth 1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d` to sync with `Ropsten` network. I started synchronization with `fast` mode and restarted the service. When I type `eth.syncing` in geth console it always shows `false` but the new blocks are being imported.

`eth.blockNumber` in my node returns **4374961** but when I try to get one of the transaction info from that block then it returns `null`.

When will the transaction info of the blocks be downloaded in my node? I already removed the test database 3 times and started fresh with `fast` sync mode. I have 11 peers right now in my node. Do I need to change something to download block info?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was on the different fork than the fork of https://ropsten.etherscan.io/blocks as stated [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/18036#issuecomment-436619155). I updated my geth server and started syncing with bootnodes available [here](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten). Now everything seems updated with `Ropsten` network.